# What types of algorithms should I look in solving? Image recognition

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, data-science

so I'm looking for an algorithm to solve this problem. Right now I'm using regression analysis with the RGB values but I'm thinking if there's a better solution.

So there's 5 training images that each represent a certain number. So like red=0%, lighter red = 0.2%, even lighter red = 0.5%, then like a different shade = 1%, etc.

Afterwards, there is another shade of red at the bottom and I wish to figure out what % that image is at. What I did to solve this problem was I made a regression to find a quartic equation for each individual RGB value and then based on that I could figure out what the % is.

Is there a better way? I want to make this to work in varying light conditions if possible.

Comment: "quartic equation" you are talking high concepts but showing nothing where is your code??

Comment: I'm talking more along a theoretical note. I found an equation that maps the R, G and B values for each of the training images. Then I simply pop in the RGB values of the bottom image and see where it lies among the equation, and that's the % value.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a more effective algorithm that perhaps takes note of HSL/HSV.

Comment: Why have you chosen a quartic? If you really have only 5 images, you theoretically CAN fit to a quadratic polynomial, but statistically speaking this is ill-advised. Do you have any physical basis for this assumption?

Comment: No, but wouldn't it be most accurate?

Comment: I also used a linear regression but it seems to be inaccurate.